# Makefile won't compile correctly

Tags: c++, makefile

I can't figure out how to get my Makefile to compile a group of cpp files using the -lpthread. The problem is occurring with g++ *.cpp -c. My functions (Which are in external files), can't find pthread_exit. What is the correct way to do this?

```
#
#Makefile for producerConsumer
#

RM = rm -f
#SRC = producer.cpp consumer.cpp
#OBJ = $(SRC:.cpp=.o)
TESTNAME = test
TESTSRC = main.cpp
#

retest: re test

test: 
    g++ *.cpp -c
    g++ *.o -o $(TESTNAME) -lpthread

clean:
    -$(RM) *.o
    -$(RM) *~
    -$(RM) \#*
    -$(RM) *.core

fclean: clean
    -$(RM) $(TESTNAME)
    -$(RM) *.o

re: fclean
```

Comment: I would expect it's not a problem with your Makefile, but with your C++-Code. I couldn't see a show-stop error in your Makefile so I tried it with the example provided [here](http://www.yolinux.com/TUTORIALS/LinuxTutorialPosixThreads.html). I added `pthread_exit(NULL)` at the end of each function in that example and gave `main()` a more sensible signature. Compiles and runs flawlessly, even with `-Wall`

Comment: It would probably add significant content to this question to also include the output of your `make clean` and `make test` requests. Just saying...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you're using Linux, so use `-pthread` instead of `-lpthread`, and make sure to add it to both the compilation and linking commands. The `-pthread` option will make sure pthread support is activated while (pre-)compiling your code, and will ensure that the correct libraries are linked in properly.

Additionally, make sure you've included `<pthread.h>` in any compilation unit that uses pthread functions, so they all look for the correct symbols.

Here's a sample makefile :

```
CXX = g++
LD = g++
CXXFLAGS = -Wall -pthread
LDFLAGS = -pthread

SOURCES = main.cpp
OBJECTS = $(SOURCES:.cpp=.o)
BINARY = test

all : $(SOURCES) $(BINARY)

$(BINARY) : $(OBJECTS) 
    $(LD) $(LDFLAGS) $^ -o $@

.cpp.o :
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -c $< -o $@

.PHONY : clean
clean :
    rm -f *.o $(BINARY)
```

Comment: Usually it is `CXX` and `CXXFLAGS` for C++, no? That way one can leverage the implicit rules.

Comment: @juanchopanza you're correct. If gnu make is indeed the host, that is totally the way to do it, as you get the cpp rules as freebies. Still, a good sample, I think.

Comment: @SanderDeDycker The bonus is you no longer need the .cpp.o rule anymore. and +1 in case it wasn't obvious.